# Struggling with key-keyref

Tags: xml, xsd, keyref

I am strugling with understanding `key:keyref` in xml.

My structure

```
<Regions>
    <Region Name="Simple region name">
        <NumberOfWineries>3</NumberOfWineries>
        <Winery Name="Simple winery">
            <City>Simple city</City>
            <Owner>Simple owner</Owner>
            <Image photo="img_winary"/>  
            <NumberOfDiffrentWines>2</NumberOfDiffrentWines>
            <Wines>
                <Wine Name="Cool wine" Vintage="2003">
                    <Characteristics>
                        <Color>blue</Color>
                    </Characteristics>
                </Wine>
            </Wines>
        </Winery>
    </Region>
    <Region....> 
        .....
    </Region>
</Regions>
```

Here I am strugling with making `key:keyref` from wine to winery.

I was thinking of making an unique `id` of winery and refering to that id for every wine.

Something like

```
<winery id="1" />
<wine idref="1" />
```

It is not so clear to me, can someone guide me if I am going on a wrong path.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the wine element is within a winery element, why do you need a key/keyref relationship? Will this have different semantics from the containment relationship?

Comment: @MichaelKay I am just studying. I am willing to change the structure as long as I can achieve key:keyref and understand it.

Comment: But "using key:keyref" is not a requirement. I need to understand what you want to achieve by using it.

Answer (score 0):

Code exmaple is following, some details are omitted:

```
<xs:element name="root" type="Root">
    <xs:key name="aKey">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//Winery"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="aKeyRef" refer="aKey">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//wine"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@wineryRef"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="Root">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Winery"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Winery">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Wines" type="wines"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="wines">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="wine" type="wine" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="wine">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="chara" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="wineryRef" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Some important notes:

- Define `key` and `keyref` in the body of element
- Use suitable XPath syntax to refer your node

You can find more examples and explanation in [my xsd tutorial](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/xsd-tutorial-3-mis.html#define-key-keyref).